# Javascript-Promise

Tags: javascript, objeto, function, promesas

Hola alguien sería tan amable de explicarme estos puntos que he dejado comentado en este ejercicio. La verdad no lo encuentro por ninguna parte y no entiendo el porque de colocarlos y que hacen y a que se refieren, quiero seguir aprendiendo y estoy un poco estancado en esta parte, cordial saludo y muchas gracias!

Código:

````
```const users=[{
id:1,
name:"Cristian"},
{id:2,
name:"Perlita"},
{id:3,
name:"Ramon"
}]

const email=[
{id:1,
email:"cristianjosehcls@gmail.com"},
{id:2,
email:"cristikajose@gmail.com"}]

const getUser=(id)=>{
const usuarios=users.find(usaurio=>usaurio.id==id)
const promise=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>
{if(!usuarios){reject(`no existe el id de users con parametro ${id}`)}else{resolve(usuarios)}
})
return promise
}
const getEmail=(user)=>{
const correos=email.find(mensajes=>mensajes.id==user.id)/*De donde sale este user.id? Si es del nombre del parametro porque el .id a que se refiere?*/
const promise=new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{if(!correos){reject (`no existe un id de correo comparativo a ${user.name}`)/*se que el user es el parametro pero el .name a que se refiere y porque se coloca y a que se refiere en todo el codigo?*/}else{resolve({id:user.id,
    name:user.name,
    email:correos.email})}}) /*no entiendo en donde sale todo este codigo:id:user.id,
    name:user.name,
    email:correos.email. Se que se crea un objeto pero nose a que corresponde cada cosa y el porque de colocarse asi?*/ 
return promise
}

getUser(1).then(positive => getEmail(positive))/*Que es lo que hace realmente positive => getEmail(positive) es decir realmente para que de la flecha y todo lo demas en el codigo, esas son todas mis dudas gracias!*/
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**getEmail()** es una funcion que retorna una  [promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) el cual recibe como parametro **user**, donde se espera que este parametro tenga la propiedades **id** y **name**.

```js
const getEmail = (user) => {
  const correos = email.find(mensajes => mensajes.id == user.id)
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!correos) {
      reject(`no existe un id de correo comparativo a ${user.name}`)
    } else {
      resolve({
        id: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        email: correos.email
      })
    }
  })
  return promise
}
```

Segun [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> El método find() devuelve el valor del primer elemento del array que
> cumple la función de prueba proporcionada.

Entonces la funcion que tiene es de obtener el primer email que tenga el mismo id que de alguno de los usuarios en el array.

```js
const correos = email.find(mensajes => mensajes.id == user.id)
```

Una `Promise` retorna un `resolve` o un `reject`, el primero se usa si se cumple el resultado esperado en este caso si existe el email entonces se crea un objeto con el **id**, **name** y el **email** del usuario. Con `reject` podemos retornar el error.

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (!correos) {
    reject(`no existe un id de correo comparativo a ${user.name}`)
  } else {
    resolve({
      id: user.id,
      name: user.name,
      email: correos.email
    })
  }
})
```

Para consumir una `Promise` se usa **.then()** para obtener los datos que se resolvieron en la promesa y **.catch()** para obtener los errores que retorna reject.

```js
getUser(1).then(user => getEmail(user))
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Entonces **positive** es lo que retorna la funcion **getUser(1)** con ese id para posteriormente pasar ese usuario como parametro a la funcion **getEmail(positive)** y asi finalmente obtener el usuario con su **id**, **name** y el **email**. Tambien es bueno resaltar que positive es solo un nombre que tu puedes asignar como en este caso yo lo cambie por **user**.

Comment: Excelente nunca mejor explicado!